# Find the point on $f(x)$ that a tangent passes through so that it passes through point $(a,b)$

Tags: calculus

How would I find a point $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $(a,b)$ lies on a line tangent to a function $f(x)$ for a given $f$?

Answer (score 1):

Compute the tangent (as a function of $x$).  Then solve for the $x$ that makes the line $y = mx + b$ go through $(x, f(x))$ and $(a,b)$.  The slope $m = \frac{b-f(x)}{a - x}$, and the intercept $b$ ensures the tangent line goes through both specified points.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent line is generally given by $y\,=\,f(x_{0})+f'(x_{0})\cdot (x-x_{0})$. Here you have $x_0=a$ and $f(x_0)=b$.

Answer (score 0):

**One possibility:**

The required point may  be the point of inflection such that $b=f(a), f'(a)=0, f''(a)=0, f''(a+h)f''(a+h)<0$. If $f(x)$ is a polynomial it has to be of degree equal to or more than 3. For instance, $y=(x-a)^3+b.$ Then the tangent $y=b$ will touch and also cut the curve at $x=a$

Answer (score 0):

Let (x,f(x)) be a point on the curve.

Line through $(x,f(x))$ and $(a,b)$ has slope

$m=\dfrac{f(x)-b}{x-a}=f'(x)$, solve for $x$;

Let $x= c$ be the solution.

Then

1) $y-f(c)=\dfrac{f(c)-b}{c-a}(x-c)$ passes through $(c,f(c)).$

2) Has slope $f'(c)$;

3) Passes through $(a,b)$.

Setting  $x=a$ in

$y-f(c)=\dfrac{f(c)-b}{c-a}(a-c)$;

gives $y=b$;